# Textview Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I want to create a Textview with a scrollview. But it doesn't work.

It's just a Textview, which is centered-

Here is the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="453dp"
android:layout_height="122dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_marginLeft="40dp">

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">



    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="453dp"
    android:layout_height="122dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:gravity="center"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16dp" 
    android:maxLines="400"


    />

   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make textView height **453dp** too

Comment: your screen color is black even your text color is black .Moreover you have not write anything in textview. How can you see anything in screen...!

Comment: ive got a white background... !"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed scroll view height

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

and make height of text View to wrap_content hope this will help

Comment: Bro that was not working because the height of scroll view was wraping full height of textView now as your text view is big and scrollView is small so its working

Answer (score 0):

You have to set Text View property simply. Don't use ScrollView

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LinearLayout` and the `TextView` are the same height. So there is now way the `ScrollView` will scoll, because the `View` inside isn't taller than the `ScrollView` itself (which can grow to the same dimensions as the `LinearLayout` outside).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `LinearLayout` and put it into the `ScrollView`.

So you have `ScrollView` on top level and in the `ScrollView` you put the `LinearLayout`. In the `LinearLayout` you got the `TextView`.